# Spring boot Specification to filter on two child entities

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, predicate, criteriaquery

There is entity by name `Transaction` which has two mapped(`@OneToOne`) child entities by name `ServiceTransaction` and `OtherFeeTransaction`.  Able to filter using Specification for all the fields but for the child entity fields at the same time.

**Transaction Entity:**

```
 public class Transaction implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(
        name = "UUID",
        strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator"
    )
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false, columnDefinition = "uuid")
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "txn_id")
    private String txnId;

    @Column(name = "account_no")
    private String accountNo;

    @Column(name = "date", nullable = false)
    private Date date;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "service_id")
    private ServiceTransaction serviceTransaction;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "other_id")
    private OtherFeeTransaction otherFeeTransaction;

    }
```

**OtherFee Entity:**

```
public class OtherFeeTransaction implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
@GenericGenerator(
    name = "UUID",
    strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator"
)
@Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false, columnDefinition = "uuid")
private UUID id;

@Column(name = "other_fee_id")
private UUID otherFeeId;

@Column(name = "type_data_id")
private String typeDataId;

}
```

**Service Entity:**

```
public class ServiceTransaction implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
@GenericGenerator(
    name = "UUID",
    strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator"
)
@Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false, columnDefinition = "uuid")
private UUID id;

@Column(name = "parcel_id")
private String cadastreId;

@Column(name = "ba_unit_id")
private String titleId;

}
```

Specification

```
Predicate service = cb.like(root.<ServiceTransaction>get("serviceTransaction").get("titleId"),
                "%" + criteria.getTitleId() + "%");

Predicate other = cb.like(root.<OtherFeeTransaction>get("otherFeeTransaction").get("typeDataId"),
                "%" + criteria.getTitleId() + "%");
//works if any one of the predicates is added, but doesn't work if both given like below
predicateList.add(service);
predicateList.add(other);

criteriaQuery.where(cb.and(predicateList.toArray(new Predicate[predicateList.size()])))
            .getRestriction();
```

If any one of the `predicate`'s `service` or `other` is given able to get the result but not if both `predicates` given.

Even tried with `or caluse` it deos not work

Comment: Please add the entities.

Comment: added the entities

Comment: And what is the problem exactly/

Comment: I dont know what is your criteria. But you should try to query database first. Maybe there is no data that is satisfied by the criteria.

Comment: Also, you created both predicates with "criteria.getTitleId()", is it correct ?

Answer (score 1):

I got it worked, Forgot to use LeftJoin on the Mapped entites

```
   Predicate service = cb.like(root.join("serviceTransaction",JoinType.LEFT).get("cadastreId"),
            "%" + criteria.getParcelId() + "%");

        Predicate other = cb.like(root.join("otherFeeTransaction",JoinType.LEFT).get("typeDataId"),
            "%" + criteria.getParcelId() + "%");

        predicateList.add(cb.or(service,other));
```